# I would like to use a single Azure key vault, share among multiple teams. Using RBAC want to allow have access to those Objects they have access to?

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I would like to use a single keyvault, share among multiple teams. I want to maintain certficates, secrets and keys and use RBAC to allow users, Groups, Service Principals to insure they only have access to those Objects they have access to ?

Comment: You can give them access to the KV, but are you looking to allow them access to only part of the keys etc.? Because that is not possible. A user either has e.g. Read access to all secrets or no Read access to secrets.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you can't.

The granularity of the data tier access control is not such meticulous,  the user/service principal/group either access all the secrets or not access all the secrets, the same for keys and certificates.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in the features available in the product, you cannot control or deploy RBAC's at data plane for customized access to KV entities such as secrets, keys, and certificates.

You may consider creating multiple instances of vaults to deploy such a pattern. At the same time, you should also voice your opinion on the feedback portal.